# Solutions to an ODE involving a positive function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $f:(0,\infty)\to(0,\infty)$ be a $C^1$ function. Then for all $y>0$, the identity
$$
f'(y)=(p-1)[f(y)]^\frac{p-2}{p-1},
$$
holds iff $f(y)=(y+k)^{p-1}$ for some constant $k$.
Does it hold?

I have got affirmative answer. Let $f(y)=(y+k)^{p-1}$ then the above identity holds and the converse part also follows by seperation of variable.

Is there something I am missing specially the converse part?

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The converse part: 
$$ f'(y) = (p-1) f(y)^{\frac{p-2}{p-1}} $$
rearranging gives
$$ f'(y) f(y)^{-\frac{p-2}{p-1}} = p-1$$
now integrating yields
$$ (p-1)f(y)^{\frac1{p-1}} =(p-1)(y+c)  $$
for some constant $c$. Thus
$$ f(y)=(y+c)^{p-1}. $$

Comment: Thanks. I am little confused about the third line aout the positivity of (y+c), because $f$ is given positive.

Comment: please have a look at the comment.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you concerned that $y+c$ might be negative?

Comment: NO I am not. But not convinced why y+c is positive.

Comment: Can you kindly elaborate.

Comment: Well for $y>0$ and  for $c>0$ $(y+c)^{p-1}$ is positive, independent of $p$.

Comment: Thanks. So $f$ is given positive, therefore from the third line of your argument $y+c$ has to be positive. Is it correct? @Mick

Comment: $f :(0,\infty)\to (0,\infty)$, i.e. it is positive and its domain is also positive, so yes.